# programmatically reset filter on jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the jquery tablesorter from Mottie with the filter widget.  Everything is working fantastic except one thing I cannot figure out.  I have the table showing up in a modal.  When you type some text in the filter box, then close the modal and reopen it, the text filter is still applied.  I want that filter cleared/reset once the modal is reopened.  I couldn't find any code to reset the filter on the tablesorter site.  I can add a button that does it, but I can't figure out the specific code that does the reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to re-initialize tablesorter (because there is a new table built) when the modal opens, then you can set the [`filter_saveFilters` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-savefilters) to `false`. The previous query won't be saved to local storage and will not get applied to the table.

If you only need to "applyWidgets" to get tablesorter to work in the modal (tablesorter is not re-initialized each time), then you'll need to clear the filters by using the [`setFilters` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#function-setfilters) as follows:

```
$.tablesorter.setFilters( $('table'), [] );
```

Comment: That was it!  I had `filter_saveFilters` set to true and I didn't even know what it was doing.  Copied it from somewhere else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just re-call tablesorter when the page reopens?

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} );
```

Comment: This doesn't work... in the original tablesorter, reinitializing tablesorter reapplies the header bindings and totally messes up stuff, like the zebra widget - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1528/). In my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), reinitializing tablesorter is completely ignored - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/884/) - I might change this behavior though.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to make this work for me was by forcing the filter fields to go empty before
re loading tablesorter.
Used:

```
$(".tablesorter-filter").val('');
$table.tablesorter({ ...options... });
```